# SSH source code example

Tags: ssh

I would like to write my own implementation of a SSH daemon that is *not* based on OpenSSL. It shall be used in a non Linux-oid environment.

Is there any public domain source code for a SSH domain (probably not full-featured) available?

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar, what package did you choose?  I've looked at Dropbear (small compared to OpenSSL, but still big) and axTLS (VERY small).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of small SSH daemons exist that may be adaptable to your environment.

If your concern is about licensing, then pick example code that is not GPL, and you'll be free to do whatever you like with it.  (Note that OpenSSH uses the BSD license, so you are free to do whatever you like with it.)  [Dropbear](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html) is a nice, small server that often gets used in embedded environments.

Also, check out Wikipedia's [Comparison of SSH servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_servers).  It's not complete, but it provides some food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to write your own daemon, can't you just read the source code of OpenSSH, if it is too complex, then you can maybe have a look on:

http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sources/contrib/blstuart/ssh/

I think this one is released under Lucent Public License Version and written i Plan 9 C, which is a little bit different to C89 or C99. But should be quite easy to understand.

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#lucent102

Or have a look on the Erlang implementation of SSH.

https://github.com/erlang/otp/tree/maint/lib/ssh/src

Good luck!

Comment: It does? Please have a look on sshsession.c, it is started from aux/listen* (similar to inetd in UN*X).

Comment: @harper, what are you talking about? From http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sources/contrib/blstuart/ssh/man/ssh2 "These programs collectively provide support for SSHv2 for Plan 9.
It supports only SSHv2 and will reject connections with a remote
system that supports only SSHv1."

Comment: @MichaelChirico: the web server is flaky. the link is accessible now...

Answer (score 1):

There are already pointers to source code samples by emil and ghoti.

But I think to start such a project you should read the documentation of the [underlying protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell).